# GCP connecting to a vm stucks on Loading Establishing connection to SSH server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM in GCP Compute Engine. However, when I am trying to connect it with web ssh, it stucks on a loader with Loading
Establishing connection to SSH server... text

I tried by stoping then starting the vm, reseting the vm, but none of them worked

Comment: Disable browser plugins and retry. Enable the web browser debugger and review error messages. Something on your side is interfering.

Comment: This official [SSH troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) from GCP website can also help you dig deeper into your investigation.